# Grab always n elements from vector, if vector length <n, loop over vector again

Tags: r, vector, element

Say I have a set of vectors of different lengths.

I want to grab always the first 9 elements from them.

However, if the vector length is <9, I want to grab all the elements, and complete up to 9 going over the vector again (and again, and again... where necessary) from the start.

For example:

`v1=LETTERS[1:15]` -> I want to grab `"A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I"`

`v2=LETTERS[1:5]` -> I want to grab `"A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D"`

`v3=LETTERS[1:3]` -> I want to grab `"A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C"`

... and so on.

Is there a simple way to do this without going over loops and exceptions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat vector when its length is not a multiple of desired total length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829481/repeat-vector-when-its-length-is-not-a-multiple-of-desired-total-length)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `rep_len()` function:

```
> rep_len(LETTERS[1:15], 9)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I"
> rep_len(LETTERS[1:5], 9)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D"
> rep_len(LETTERS[1:3], 9)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C"
```

Alternatively, there is also the `rep()` function, with the `length.out` argument, which would give you the same result, however `rep()` is slightly slower than `rep_len()`.

You can read the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/rep).

Comment: Use rep_len, it is a faster version of length.out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11829593/680068

Answer (score 7):

I think the [`rep` approach by @Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76616759/12158757) is the most straightforward and efficient way for you question.

If you are interested in coding practice, you can try defining a function like below

```
f <- function(v, n) {
    v[(seq(n) - 1) %% length(v) + 1]
}
```

such that

```
> f(LETTERS[1:9], 9)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I"

> f(LETTERS[1:5], 9)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "A" "B" "C" "D"

> f(LETTERS[1:3], 9)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C"
```